# error in executeQuery in jdbc connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have a table in my  data base that has two column `id` and `name` . i wrote a class for get and set value of this two column . 
my getCourseName is :

```
public String getCourseName(int id) throws SQLException {
    String SQL = "select * from courses where id ="+id;
    Connection con = c.getCon();
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
    String nm = res.getString("name");

    return nm;
}
```

when i run this function , its show error http status 500 exception :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoou forgot to call `res.next();` after `executeQuery`. This call advances the result set to point to the first returned row (assuming any row was returned). Each additional call to it advances the result set to the next row.

```
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
String nm = null;
if (res.next()) {
  String nm = res.getString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic mistake `ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(SQL);` this gives you a `ResultsetObject`

Now the question comes what is `ResultSet`

*A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.*

So that means you need to iterate over the resultsetObject obtained to get the column values.
Something like this

```
while(resultSetObject.next())
{
  String name = resultSetObject.getString("yourColumnName");
}
```

***Note** Always try using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` to avoid `sql-injection`

So in that case it will be something like this

```
String SQL = "select * from courses where id = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1,id);
ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getCourseName(int id) throws SQLException {
    String SQL = "select * from courses where id ="+id;
    Connection con = c.getCon();
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
    String nm = null;
    if(res.next())
      nm = res.getString("name");
    con.close();
    return nm;
}
```